# How to Display data in a linear fashion

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using this example found [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL-Server-2005/Q_22938684.html)

> I have a report i want to create which
>   will show me infomation like the
>   following:
>
> Account ID , DateEntered, DateFirst
>   contact was made, Dealt by, Date 2nd
>   contact was made, Dealt by....
>
> However all this information is heald
>   in one table but the info comes like
>   this  (See example in link)
>
> Now i would like to see the data like
>   this in a linear fashion:
>
> 123       12-04-07      John 14-04-07      Mary          15-06-07 Cait
>
> However differnt accounts will have
>   different amounts of data in it so
>   some may have 5 rows othere could have
>   ten?

I would like to display data in a linear fashion so that each row is unique. In the case of the example, the unique identifier would be the accountID. My personal scenario is a bit different in that I have the data in several tables but can easily join them to get a similar output to the above example. Where I am having trouble is making the data linear so that each row is unique and does not repeat for each different variance.

Can this be done?

Comment: Could you post some most information on the tables that you're using?

Comment: If you follow the link in the original post, the table structure is defined there.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which SQL Server version are you using or the number of rows are fixed or not for each account id. The above information restricts which solution needs to be used and these below will help you achieve what you want or reply back with additional details.

http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx
http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-create-a-cross-tab-or-pivot-query.html
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1019

Comment: All of the PIVOT examples I've looked at use some aggregate function to tally the count or sum or max or whatever for the pivot table. I'm looking for a final result set with "n" number of columns for each row based on how many related records there are.